# Prove two identities relating to series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Show that:
$$(1)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ln\left(\cos \frac{x}{2^n}\right)=\ln\frac{\sin x}x$$

$$(2). \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2^n}\tan \frac{x}{2^n}=\frac1x-\cot x$$

Thank you in advance.

NOTE:
The origial problem (1) I stated is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\cos \frac{x}{2^n}\right)=\ln\frac{\sin x}x$, which is a mistake as noted by the comments below.

Comment: For (1), do you mean to have the limit or no?

Comment: $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty}\cos\dfrac{x}{2^n}$ doesn't exist for any $n$.

Comment: @MathNoob: Yes, The problem has the limit.

Comment: In that case, (1) is wrong, as per @JimmyK4542's comment.

Comment: @MathNoob: Er, I'll check it. How about problem (2)?

Comment: It is true that $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\ln\left(\cos \dfrac{x}{2^n}\right) = \ln \dfrac{\sin x}{x}$. Perhaps that is what the problem meant. Problem 2 is correct as is (according to WolframAlpha).

Comment: In (1) There is no "unbound" x - $x$ is not a variable.

Comment: Thank you very much. Maybe you are right. Can be provide me with the details?

Comment: @Integrator : OK, thank you. But I think the two problems have some similarities. I will do it as what you suggested later.

Comment: @Roger209 The two problems are very much connected. Differentiating both sides of (1) will give you (2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For (1) Consider the product $P_N = \displaystyle\prod_{n = 1}^{N}\cos\dfrac{x}{2^n}$. Multiply by $\sin\dfrac{x}{2^N}$ and use the identity $\cos\theta\sin\theta = \dfrac{1}{2}\sin 2\theta$ repeatedly to get $P_N\sin\dfrac{x}{2^N} = \dfrac{1}{2^N}\sin x$.

Therefore, $P_N = \dfrac{\sin x}{2^N\sin\frac{x}{2^N}} \to \dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ as $N \to \infty$. Hence, $\displaystyle\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}\cos\dfrac{x}{2^n} = \dfrac{\sin x}{x}$.

Take the natural log of both sides to get $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\ln\left(\cos\dfrac{x}{2^n}\right) = \ln\left(\dfrac{\sin x}{x}\right)$, as desired.

For (2) differentiate both sides of the result from (1) and multiply by $-1$. (Thanks David H for this suggestion).

Comment: Thank you for your helpful hint and answer. I finally worked it out  with your help.

Comment: @Roger209 The second sum we can make it telescope as well ! :-) (I edited on my answer)

Answer (score 2):

For the first one :

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \ln \cos \frac{x}{2^n} = \ln \prod\limits_{n=1}^{N} \cos \frac{x}{2^n} = \ln \frac{\sin \frac{x}{2^N}\prod\limits_{n=1}^{N} \cos \frac{x}{2^n}}{\sin \frac{x}{2^N}} = \ln \frac{\sin x}{2^N\sin \frac{x}{2^N}}$$

where, we made use of the identity: $\sin y \cos y = \frac{1}{2}\sin 2y$ repeatedly.

Taking limit as $N \to \infty$, we have $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln\big(\cos \frac{x}{2^n}\big)=\ln \frac{\sin x}{x}$

For the second one use the identity: $$\tan y = \cot y - 2\cot 2y$$

So, $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{2^n} \tan \frac{x}{2^n} = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{2^n}\left(\cot \frac{x}{2^n} - 2\cot \frac{x}{2^{n-1}} \right) = \frac{1}{2^{N}}\cot \frac{x}{2^N} - \cot x$

Taking the limit as $N \to \infty$,

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \tan \frac{x}{2^n} = \frac{1}{x} - \cot x$$

Comment: It doesn't mean anything to say as $N\to\infty$ we have $\sin \frac{x}{2^N} \to \frac{x}{2^N}$. You can say $$\frac{\sin \frac{x}{2^N}}{\frac{x}{2^N}}\to 1$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks ! I understand :-)